# Should I Include RSS Feed URLs in an XML Sitemap?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, rss, xml-sitemap

Simple question - Should I Include the RSS Feed URLs in my site's XML Sitemap?

I am NOT asking whether I should USE an RSS Feed AS an XML sitemap, but rather, should I include the URLs to the various RSS feeds on my site in my XML Sitemap?

I am looking for both general advice, and/or pointers to any relevant documentation supporting an answer to my question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't include RSS feed urls in your sitemap.  RSS feeds don't make good landing pages. I've never seen any evidence that Google wants to index them.  As such, they are not a good fit for sitemap inclusion. They will clutter up the webmaster tools stats of the pages that you do care about. They won't provide any benefit to Google.

Answer (score 5):

No you shouldn't include them in a regular sitemap, as they are not web pages. Even so, they are essentially just links to actual pages in your site.

However, it should be fine to include them in a sitemap index file, because Google recognises RSS feeds as sitemaps.

Comment: Regarding your second point, this is only advisable if the rss feed content is not already contained in a formal xml sitemap.